# Crystal Report not display in Crystal report viewer

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

i try to use Crystal report viewer to show crystal report in my website. But it not show anything. Why ? Please Help me please.

this is my code (Code behide)

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["AppRowId"]))
        {
            string xAppRowId = Request.QueryString["AppRowId"];
            ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
            ParameterValues p1s = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue Pval = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            Pval.Value = xAppRowId;
            p1s.Add(Pval);

            // report.FileName = Server.MapPath(@"~/CrystalReport/CrystalReportAppForm.rpt");
            report.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperA4;
            report.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~/CrystalReport/CrystalReportAppForm.rpt"));
            //// ReportViewer1.DataBinding = report;
            report.DataDefinition.ParameterFields["AppRowId"].ApplyCurrentValues(p1s);

            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;

        }
```

this is my crystal report viewer in aspx

```
  <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" PrintMode="ActiveX" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" EnableParameterPrompt="False" ToolPanelView="None" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
```

And this is my assembly in webconfig file

```
 <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

My .Net framework is 4, i'm spend a lot of time for this. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you so much

Comment: Please check that your crystal report data source has a records to show on report. How you binding data to report.

Comment: I send rowId to Parameter["AppRowId"]. In crystal report when i press f5(run report) it will show promote parameter to assign value then it will show data. How to do in asp.net c# like that ?

Comment: I can see that you missed the @ with parameter. Add @ with parameter value like report.SetParameterValue("@AppRowId", xAppRowId); and remove this line there is no need of it CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();

Comment: @ use for formula right ?

Comment: it is syntax for parameter name.

Comment: it's syntax for formula, I already try it.

Comment: @SainPradeep        please check my update quest at code behide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80155/discussion-between-user3001046-and-sain-pradeep).

Comment: Did you create the report in Crystal Reports or in Visual Studio? From my experience, I've had to create the reports in visual studio, importing previously created reports from Crystal causes errors like this. EDIT: Didn't realise this was over 3 years old when I left a comment. I retract.